# haskell list to list pattern matching

Tags: haskell

Here's my code:

```
newcell :: [Cell] -> [Cell]
newcell [Cell {cellPosition = cp, cellState = cs}] 
= [Cell {cellPosition = cp, cellState = (nextCellState cs)}]
```

`nextCellState` is just a function, but it says could not match the pattern.

```
src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs:141:1: Warning:
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘newcell’:
    Patterns not matched:
        []
        (Cell _ _) : (_ : _)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are only matching the pattern of a single Cell in a list. Take another look at the error message. It tells you exactly what patterns you need to match.

The empty list:

```
[]
```

And the pattern of more than one Cell in the list:

```
(Cell _ _) : (_ : _)
```